# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Assign incrementing value

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need to assign an incrementing value to each string from the concatenated row starting at 0 for each row in the result.

Here's a simplified data sample:

```
number|color
1     |red
1     |blue
1     |orange
2     |brown
3     |purple
3     |yellow
```

This is the result that I need:

```
number|color_set
1     |0 red,1 blue,2 orange
2     |0 brown
3     |0 purple,1 yellow
```

This is the result that I get:

```
number|color_set
1     |0 red,1 blue,2 orange
2     |3 brown
3     |4 purple,5 yellow
```

This is what I've been trying:

```
SET @x:=0;

SELECT number, GROUP_CONCAT(@x:=@x+1,' ',color SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table
GROUP BY number;
```

The variable needs to be reset to 0 for each result row. I'm no expert obviously and I'm new to the site so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Agree with @Strawberry.  It's often better to perform grouping in the application layer than to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in this way.

Comment: The thing is, there's no 'natural order' in mysql, so there's no reason why red should be 0 instead of 1

Comment: I have to concatenate these results with a bunch of other code so I can populate a coupon table on a Magento e-commerce site that I own, but did not design. I'm not a developer but I know a little bit of SQL/MySQL so bear with me. Right now, I have 5984 records in that table which slows down the shopping cart process. I've rounded off the discount amounts to 393 unique values with anywhere from 1 to 67 different product codes for each. The site requires each of those product codes to be preceded by a numeric value starting at zero and increasing by increments of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun...

```
 CREATE TABLE colors(color_set INT NOT NULL,color VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (color_set,color));

 INSERT INTO colors VALUES
 (1     ,'red'),
 (1     ,'blue'),
 (1     ,'orange'),
 (2     ,'brown'),
 (3     ,'purple'),
 (3     ,'yellow');


      SELECT color_set
      , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',n,color) ORDER BY n) array
   FROM
      ( SELECT c.*
             , FIND_IN_SET(color,x)-1 n 
          FROM colors c
          JOIN 
             ( SELECT color_set
                    , GROUP_CONCAT(color ORDER BY LENGTH(color),color) x 
                 FROM colors 
                GROUP 
                   BY color_set
             ) y
            ON y.color_set = c.color_set
      ) z
  GROUP 
     BY color_set;

 +-----------+-----------------------+
 | color_set | array                 |
 +-----------+-----------------------+
 |         1 | 0 red,1 blue,2 orange |
 |         2 | 0 brown               |
 |         3 | 0 purple,1 yellow     |
 +-----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. This worked perfect. Thanks, Jay

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered, but isn't this an easier way? Just add @x:=0 to the select?

SET @x:=0;

SELECT number, GROUP_CONCAT(@x:=@x+1,' ',color SEPARATOR ','),@x:=0
FROM table
GROUP BY number;

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is very helpful and shortest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution in 2 steps? Or does it have to be 1 SQL query only?

1. Create a temporary table with (id, color), declare id as an auto increment, set the start of the auto increment to 0 (`ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;`)
2. Select and insert whichever records you want transformed (`INSERT INTO ttTable SELECT color FROM datatable WHERE number = 3`), then read them back out and generate the list via `GROUP_CONCAT`. You have to repeat this step for all numbers in the original table.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I need to add this to an existing query so it needs to be 1 SQL query. Thanks, Jay

Answer (score 0):

Also just for fun...

```
SELECT
number,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(counter, ' ', color)) 
FROM (
SELECT
number,
color,
@counter := CASE WHEN @prev = number THEN @counter + 1 ELSE 0 END AS counter,
@prev := number
FROM
yourTable yt
, (SELECT @counter:=0, @prev:=NULL) vars
) sq
GROUP BY number
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9120/3/0)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. This did not give the desired result. The values did not start at zero and were non-sequential. Thanks, Jay

Comment: Then change the 1 to 0, like in my edited answer. Apart from that it's the same as Strawberry's. Sorry that I left a little bit of thinking to you.